# jQuery getJSON problem

Tags: jquery

```
$.getJSON( "http://yoolk.dev:3012/categories?callback=?", function(data) {
    console.log(data)
 }
);
```

I have the code above in order to get json data, but callback function seems not be working. Anyone can help? Thanks

Comment: What lives at `http://yoolk.dev:3012/categories` and does it support a callback?

Comment: No it doesn't. I couldn't see the data in console in firefox. I don't know why. any idea?

Answer (score 1):

if the request fails, your callback wont be called. you can use something like the example below to detect the failure. jquery will not call any error handlers in case of a `jsonp` failure... so, one can implement a timer that checks the result...

here, `task.run` does the ajax request, and the `checkStatus` function checks the result.

```
var task = {
  complete: 0,
  timeout: 5000,

  run: function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      url: 'http://www.yahoo.com',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      timeout: this.timeout,
      complete: function(req, status) {
        this.complete = 1
        if (status == "success") {
          alert('Success');
        } else {
          alert('Error: ' + status)
        }
      }
    })

    var o = this
    setTimeout(function() {o.checkStatus()}, this.timeout + 1000)
  },

  checkStatus: function() {
    if (!this.complete) {
      alert('Error: Request did not complete')
    }
  }
}

task.run()
```

Comment: What is the best solution for this?

Comment: you can use the above to check the status (will timeout after 5s). to find out why the request is failing, check the Net tab in Firebug (select "All" as the request type) and see the input/output data